# Sulu: how to query custom entity type?

Tags: entity, sulu

I have defined custom entity type "matches" and it is back-end editable, everything works as expected.

Now I need a way to query content in that type. Can smart content field type do that? I expected that xml like this would do the trick:

```
   <property name="matches" type="smart_content">
        <!-- @see https://docs.sulu.io/en/2.2/reference/content-types/smart_content.html -->
        <meta>
            <title lang="en">Matches</title>
            <title lang="de">Streichhölzer</title>
        </meta>

        <params>
            <param name="provider" value="lists"/>
            <param name="types" value="matchevents"/>
            <param name="max_per_page" value="5"/>
            <param name="page_parameter" value="m"/>
        </params>
    </property>
```

But that didn't help. Can it be done with "smart_content" field type? I yes - how? If no - what would be the best way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to create a custom `DataProvider` for your entity and then use your provider in the xml-definition.

So you have to create a repository which implements the `DataProviderRepositoryInterface`. This repository is used to query the entity.
Furthermore you also have to create the actual dataprovider service. This class should extend form the `BaseDataProvider` and finally you have to make the service definition with the tag `sulu.smart_content.data_provider` and an alias.

The alias is used in the xml-file e.g.

```
   <property name="matches" type="smart_content">
    <meta>
        <title lang="en">Matches</title>
        <title lang="de">Streichhölzer</title>
    </meta>

    <params>
        <param name="provider" value="myCustomDataProviderAlias"/>
    </params>
</property>
```

Check out the documentation for a step by step tutorial on how to create a custom data provider. https://docs.sulu.io/en/2.2/cookbook/smart-content-data-provider.html#how-to-create-a-custom-dataprovider

Comment: This documentation is partly ok, but some key information is missing: where to store data item class file? Where to store xml code that defines service?

Comment: It is up to you and your project structure, where you want to store the `DataItemClass`, there is no specific location.

The service definition depends if you are implementing a bundle or using the custom provider directly in your project. If you are using it directly in your project, the service can be defined in the `services.yml` file similar to this one https://github.com/sulu/sulu-demo/blob/master/config/services.yaml#L42 
In symfony every service can either be defined in a `xml`, `yaml` or `php` configuration. [symfony docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/tags.html)

Comment: Thank you. Just one more hint needed - how would those "factory-method" and "factory-service" parameters from XML look like in YAML version? From here: https://docs.sulu.io/en/2.2/cookbook/smart-content-data-provider.html#service-definition

Comment: best way to check the different mappings is the symfony documentation :) here you can see the different possibilities [symfony factories documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/2.1/components/dependency_injection/factories.html)